# C++: Why doesn't this sync() work in this Composition pattern?

Tags: c++, algorithm, composition

I'm trying to build a progressbar class that can have an arbitrary number of subprogressbars by using something that looks like the composition pattern.

let's say I have this class `pbar`:

```
class pbar
{
    public:
        pbar(const int w) { width = w; } // already sets the
        ~pbar() {}

         void setwidth(const int w) { width = w; } // set the width to w
         void show() const;
         void sync();

         void add(const pbar bar)
         {
              // add's a subbar
              subbars.pushback(bar);
         }

     private:
         std::vector<pbar> subbars; // the sub-process progressbars
         int width;                 // onscreen width of the pbar
};
```

As you can see the `pbar` has two members: the width and the subprogressbars (which are themselves `pbars`). I've been trying to implememt a `sync` function wich changes all the widths of the `pbars` in `subbars` to match that of the `pbar` it was called from:

```
void pbar::sync()
{
    for ( pbar bar : subbars )
    {
         bar.setwidth(width);  // first set the width of the subbar
         bar.sync();           // secondly make it sync up it's subbars
    }
}
```

but this does not seem to work. I've tried using this test program:

```
int main()
{
    pbar a(1);
    pbar b(2);
    pbar c(3);
    pbar d(4);

    c.add(d);
    b.add(c);
    a.add(b);

    a.show();
    std::cout << "syncing" << std::endl;
    a.sync();
    a.show();
}
```

with the `show` function defined as:

```
void pbar::show() const
{
    std::cout << w << std::endl;
    for ( pbar bar : subbars )
    {
         bar.show();
    }
}
```

The expected output would be:

```
1
1
1
1
```

yet it is:

```
1
2
3
4
```

The strange this is that the `show()` function does properly iterate down to all the subbars, but it looks like the `sync()` doesn't (in fact, using `cout` I've affirmed that in actually *does*, but it seems to have no effect).

What is wrong with my code? It is not the use of the `c++0x` type for loop, because I've tried using older iterator loops. I cannot find the mistake I made. I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm changing the wrong `pbar`s when using `setwidth` in `sync`.

*disclaimer: this is actually part of a larger project and the class is a lot more complicated than is shown here, but I've managed to reproduce the unwanted behaviour using the above code (which by the way is not copy-pasted and might contain typo's)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is not the use of the c++0x type for loop

Actually, depending on what you really want to do, it might just be the range-based `for` loop you're using.

As posted in the question, the `subbars` vector stores copies of the objects added to it - that may or may not be what you want.  Lets assume that it is what you want.  The range-based for loop that  you have right now in `pbar::sync()`:

```
for ( pbar bar : subbars )
{
    // ...
}
```

iterates over the `subbars` vector, but the `bar` variable in this case is itself a *copy* of each element in that `subbars` vector.  So any changes you make to that variable are simply lost after each iteration of the `for` loop.

However, if you change the range-based `for` loop like so:

```
for ( pbar& bar : subbars ) // note the `&`
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, `bar` is a reference to the object in the `subbars` vector and changes made to it will 'stick'.

Keep in mind, however, that since `subbars` contains copies of the object that were added to it, those changes will not propagate to the original objects added.  Whether or not that's what you want depends on what it is you want.  If you want the changes to propagate all the way to the originals, then you need to store pointers (or smart pointers) to the originals instead of copies, as is [mentioned in visier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10668582/12711).

Comment: this was actually the behaviour looked for !

Answer (score 5):

The issue you are having is that you're using a local variable, "bar" in the loop in your sync() method. That is making a copy of each of your subbars, and manipulating the copy rather than the original version (which remains in the vector). This is why you don't seen the changes "stick" when you later call the show() method.

You can probably fix this by using a reference instead of a regular variable. Try:

```
for ( pbar &bar : subbars )
{
    ...
}
```

You might want to make a similar change in your addSubBar() method, since you're also copying the values that you're passing in before saving another copy in the vector. You can skip one copy by making its parameter a reference. Avoiding the second copy would require some more care to deal with memory (which I'll leave for another question).

Answer (score 4):

You should store pointers to sub `pbars`. In the current situation you are just storing copies of the sub `pbars`. So although they (internal copies) are changed, the outer object are not modified.

Comment: so there's no way to change an object that's already in a vector without using pointers!? wow, didn't know that. must be from using too much pointers these last weeks.

Comment: @romeovs No, your code _does_ change the subbars you stored. The only problem is that you are storing _copies_ of your original subbars to begin with (in the `add()` function), as vizier already pointed out.

Comment: @Gnosophilon: I don't think so, actually.  I agree with Blckknght that he's changing the iterator variable, which is a copy of the stored subbar.  Besides, the widths being printed are those of the stored subbars, not the `b`, `c`, `d` instances.

Comment: @Gnosophilon Actually looking at his code again, even if the internal copies are modified his `a.show();` would display the internal modified copies would it not? Which should be displaying '1 1 1 1'

Comment: @VictorT.: the `show()` function is displaying the internal copies in the `subbars` vector, but those internal copies are never modified because the loop variable is yet another copy of those elements (so the changes made to it are discarded).

Comment: what I wanted was for the internal `pbar`s to be altered, not external. But the loop wasn't even doing that because of a missing `&` as Michael Burr pointed out.

Comment: @BenVoigt You are right, I missed that (ditto for Victor T.).

Answer (score 0):

you should be stored the reference of the `pbars` instead of instance copy.